Empty page with 404 errors when deploying Vite + Vue app to gh-pages, despite config files
I am in the process of creating a to-do list in Vue.js 3 to learn it and decided to deploy it to gh-pages as it is partially usable already. I am a complete beginner in Vue, I have previously worked with React and had the same issue when deploying (empty page), but can't remember how I have managed to fix it.
I have base and publicPath inside my vite.config and vue.config set to my repo name, I have also tried setting homepage property of package.json file to the entire URL where the project should be accessible.
The page is empty, upon inspection I get 404 errors, as the GET request links do not contain the repo name. The requested link for example is: https://username.github.io/assets/index-idojGXCl.js instead of https://username.github.io/repo-name/assets/index-idojGXCl.js (the same thing happens for the requested favicon and .css file). It seems as though my settings get ignored.
I use yarn to build and deploy using "yarn run build" and then "yarn run gh-pages -d dist", I have my source set to github actions and have experimented with a workflow, but haven't dove into it deeply. Perhaps my problem is that I have tried too many things.
I have been trying to fix this issue for a few hours now with the help of the internet, but where the blog posts and videos claim that it should work, I still only get a blank page. I am unsure how to fix this issue as I believe the issue could be anywhere at this point.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I have managed to solve the problem by adding a / at the end of the homepage url in package.json file and setting the repository to deploy from branch gh-pages instead of github actions. Follow this article: https://medium.com/@aishwaryaparab1/deploying-vite-deploying-vite-app-to-github-pages-166fff40ffd3 but substitute import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react' with import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue' and plugins: [react()], with plugins: [vue()], and it should work.
